# Java streams modify elements but get all the elements in origianal list

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have a java stream in which I have to apply operations to only some objects but I wanted to get the stream with the same number of elements. for example.

I have User class.

```
class User {
  String name;
  String balance;
  String company;
}
```

I want to increase the balance by 50 of all the users who have an existing balance of 500 or above. In return List, I also need the users which do not have their balance modified,

```
[   {
        "name": "john"
        "balance":  450
        "company": "AAA"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Susana"
        "balance":  "550"
        "company": "BBB"
    },
    {
        "name": "Peter"
        "balance":  "300"
        "company": "CCC"
    }
]
```

the return should be

```
[   {
        "name": "john"
        "balance":  450
        "company": "AAA"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Susana"
        "balance":  "600"
        "company": "BBB"
    },
    {
        "name": "Peter"
        "balance":  "300"
        "company": "CCC"
    }
]
```

In the same order as the original one but the records modified which meets the condition.
Any idea how could I do it with streams and functional way, no if-else, etc

I have tried the `filter` method but it just passes the filtered values downstream.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Shouldn’t the type of `balance` be numeric rather than textual?

Comment: functional programming favors immutability so you can not change original collection.

Comment: The post says *"I have tried the `filter` method but it just passes the filtered values downstream."*. Is it that we don't trust that?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
users
.stream()
.filter( user -> user.getBalance() >= 500 ) 
.forEach( user -> { user.setBalance( user.getBalance() + 50 ) } ) ;
```

The `forEach` is a terminal operation, completing the stream’s work.

**No need to return a new list.** Your original list of `User` objects named `users` remains. Some of that original list’s contained objects will have been modified by the `forEach`.

## Details

You do not need a stream. A simple `for` loop will do.

```java
for( User user : users )
{
    int b = user.getBalance() ;
    if ( b >= 500 ) { user.setBalance( b + 50 ) ; }
}
```

If you have a stream, use [`Stream#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) to get the same effect as a `for` loop.

```
users
.stream()
.forEach( user -> {
    if ( user.getBalance() >= 500 ) 
    {
        user.setBalance( user.getBalance() + 50 ) ;
    }
}) ;
```

I would say the `for` loop is a bit easier to read, in this case. Streams are not always advantageous.

You said:

> no if-else

At some point you *must* do a comparison to see if the current balance is over 500. So an `if-else` is the obvious way to make that comparison. Streams do not provide any magic with regard to comparing a number.

```
users
.stream()
.filter( user -> user.getBalance() >= 500 ) 
.forEach( user -> { user.setBalance( user.getBalance() + 50 ) } ) ;
```

As [commented by ernest_k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71738202/java-streams-modify-elements-but-get-all-the-elements-in-origianal-list/71738382#comment126778889_71738382), you could call the setter on *all* elements while employing a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Computer_science) to compare the balance to 500. If under 500, add zero. If meeting our threshold, add fifty.

```
users
.stream()
.forEach( user -> 
    user.setBalance( 
        user.getBalance() + 
        ( user.getBalance() >= 500 ? 50 : 0 ) 
    ) 
) ;
```

This more compact approach would *not* be appropriate if it triggered side-effects such as pointless writes to a database.

Comment: Perhaps *always* calling the setter can make it shorter... `.forEach(u -> u.setBalance(u.getBalance() + (u.getBalance() > 500 ? 50 : 0)));`